# Is there any unequals() method in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I'm very new to C# and I'm writing some small examples.

I have a list like:

```
var myList = {2,2,5,4,7,8,10,11,12,8,9};
```

I know the following will check if the list contains a "0":

```
myList.Equals(0);
```

But how to check that the list does not contain a "0"?
Is there something like:

```
myList.UnEquals(0);
```

Or

```
!myList.Equals(0);
```

Comment: what about a simple `!myList.Contains(0)`? also: your assumption about `.Equals()` is wrong.

Comment: Ok I see now. I misunderstood the Equals(). In my case the !Contains will do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Boolean check = myList.Contains(0);
```

Will output a `Boolean` ( true/false), false means it does not contain (0)

You can then use this in an `If` Statement to do some actions

```
If(mylist.Contains(0))
{
    //Some Actions
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `UnEquals` or `NotEquals` method, as it isn't needed. But first, the `Equals` method on a object is used to check, well, equality. If you want to check whether or not a list contains a certain value, use the [`List.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-5.0) method.

Now, why isn't it needed? Because we have the not operator, the `!`. And since a boolean value can ever only be `true` or `false` we use the not operator to negate them. So the code you're looking for is

```cs
bool doesNotContainZero = !myList.Contains(0);
```

So doing something like this:

```cs
if (!myList.Contains(0))
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Can be read as

> If my list does not contain 0, then do stuff

Answer (score 1):

@Mostafa Tarek Yassien Already answered very well, You should use myList.Contains(0).  I'll just add as your are new to C#, that you can use any function that returns a Boolean result directly into a logical evaluation statement such as ( if, while, switch).

eg:
If ( mylist.Contains(0) )
{
.... do your stuff here
}

This is very useful, as you must of the times use would use the result to make a decision in your code.

Comment: Yes, The use of `If` Statement will be very practical if he wants to build a code based on the result of the `Boolean`